# Exponential decaying Swept / chirp signal

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, octave

I'm trying to create a chirp/swept signal that has it's frequency going down exponentially using matlab/octave.  I can't use the built in chirp function because I'm trying to create a chirp/swept signal based on an equation/formula.  I tried creating some code below but as you see from the spectrogram the frequency does not end at the correct frequency, and the frequency doesn't go down exponentially.

```
clear all,clc
freq1=20; %start freq
freq2=200; %end freq
fs=44100;
dur=1; %duration of signal in seconds

t = linspace(0,2*pi,fs*dur);

f=freq1:(freq2-freq1)/length(t):freq2-(freq2-freq1)/length(t); 
%20:(200-20)/lenght(t) :200-(200-20)/length(t)

data=sin(f.*t); %build signal
data=(data/max(abs(data))*.8); %normalize signal
wavwrite([data'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
plot(t,data)
```

Here's a spectrogram plot 
[image: spectrogram plot]

My goal:

1) create a signal based on a given equation/formula where the frequency is exponentially decaying (based on the formula 1/exp)

2) be able to type in the starting and ending frequency along with it's duration in seconds example 
startfreq=20; endfreq=200; durseconds=2;

The spectrogram plot should look something like this if the start frequency is 200hz ending at 20hz.

Any ideas?

[image: what the spectrogram should look like]

Comment: This is too close to asking for software designed to a specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frequency is the derivative of phase, so you need to start with the expression for frequency, which in your case is
$f=200\exp(-\alpha*t)$

At time $t=0$ this will have the frequency of 200, but we need to solve for $\alpha$ so that the frequency at time $t=2$ is 20.  Solving for $\alpha$ gives $\alpha=1.1513$.
To get the correct expression for the phase you need to integrate the above expression for the phase i.e. solve

$f =\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}$

The following matlab code generates this signal.

```
fs=500; %sampling frequency
t=(0:2*fs)/fs; %Time vector
alpha=1.1513;
sig = exp(-j*2*pi*200/alpha*exp(-alpha*t));
```

Note that just because the instantaneous frequency behaves this way doesn't mean the spectrogram will follow it exactly. It will get better if you have a higher time-bandwidth product.

Comment: thanks so much..I'm trying to work the problem but I'm a little confused.  How did you get? $$\alpha$$.  I couldn't figure out how you got 1.1513.  $$\left[ \alpha={{\log \left({{200}\over{f}}\right)}\over{t}}
  \right] {\tt }$$

Comment: @RickT Your other requirement was for the frequency to be 20 at time $t=2$, substituting those numbers into the equation for $f$ gives $20=200\exp(-\alpha*2)$. Solving for $\alpha$ gives $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}\ln (20/200)$.